# mySQL database password change now crashes Joomla

Tags: mysql, backup, joomla, passwords, revert

I have a mySQL database behind a Joomla install. I changed the database password because I forgot it but now Joomla crashes looking for the database.

I guess joomla has the password written somewhere - if anyone knows I might be able to manual edit it and enter the new database password.

Otherwise I'm hoping a manual install of a backup of the original database will work. I need to know does a backup include the database password. If yes, will reinstating my original database solve the problem for me by reverting the system back to it's original password?

Please help.
thx,
s.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to look at your configuration.php and thease variables which sets your database connection:

```
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'your database username';
var $password = 'your database password';
var $db = 'database name';
var $dbprefix = 'jos_';
```

The file should be in your joomla-root.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but even after changing $password joomla still crashed. It turned out that when I'd changed the password the new password was too long, and was being truncated (either by joomla or mysql, I'm not sure which). So you could try using a shorter password if the above solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the above worked for me, but the password should be down at the bottom of the list of var's

Answer (score 0):

**The most simple solution is :-**

1. Use phpMyAdmin to change "email" address and copy the "username" of 
   Admin
2. Goto 'yoursite.com/administrator'
3. Click forgot password then paste "username"
4. Click password reset in your email app